# Scala apply method

Tags: scala, syntax, apply

if `List(1,2,3)` transforms to `List.apply(1,2,3)` then why `new Array[String](3)` does not transform to new Array[String].apply(3)?

I tried Array.apply(3) but the semantic is different from `new Array[String](3)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `new Array[String](3)` you are calling the Array constructor on the [Array class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html) with a single argument: 3.  Alternatively, when you call `Array(3)` you are calling the apply method on the [Array object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array%24.html).  In Java this is known as a static method call.  It is the same as calling `Array.apply(3)`, as you expected.

Answer (score 2):

the use of `new` means the mechanism is not of a function application, but construction. The code "translates" to allocating memory and calling the constructor.

Comment: is there any way to construct an object without calling new?

Comment: @user477768 You create objects all the time without using `new`, many of which you won't even notice (function literals, enrichment classes etc). You can call some factory method that creates the object for you (probably ultimately using a `new`). You can use reflection (`classOf[Foo].newInstance`). You can manipulate bytecode if you're really keen...

Answer (score 1):

Beware of the difference between

```
val a = new Array(3)
```

and

```
val a = Array(3)
```

The first creates a new `Array` object with 3 `null` elements; the second creates a new Array object with one element, which is 3.

`Array(3)` translates to `Array.apply(3)`, exactly the same as how `List(3)` translates to `List.apply(3)`.